# Big code refactoring : create a new project or refactor package per package

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database-design, refactoring

We are a little team working on a Rails 2.3 project. A short description: this project has currently

- 460 000 lines of Ruby, CSS, JS and YML (including some plugins and libraries)
- 350 ActiveRecord classes (only the project's classes)
- some Rspec tests in the recent classes and controllers (not enough)
- 45 required gems
- A database with 2 Go data.

The project is divided in approximately 15 'modules' (not as Rails module), with each module talking to others modules. This project exists from several years, and has been improved and maintained with several people, not necessary Rails experts.

The current main problem is that several parts of the code are difficultly maintainable, are unoptimized and not enough 'thoughful' (there is hack everywhere). The CSS files are nearly unreadable.

Our team is cogitating about refactoring this project. We have a few solutions :

- Create a new project from scratch, and include functionnalities one by one. The advantage of this solution is that we have all the facets of the projects, and we can take prettier decitions about code design. An other advantage is that we can update to Rails 3. A lack of this method is that we have to maintain 2 projects in parrallel, when we have to include new functionnalities.
- Update existing code, module by module. The advantage of this solution is that we keep only one project to maintain. But there is several lacks... How to go from an old module to a new module ? How to proceed between the new and old class names ? How to know where old code is inused and must be deleted ?... and even more.

Does anyone already have done a big refactoring like this ?

Does anyone have experience feedback about this ?

Does anyone have an other solution ?

Thanks for reading !

Comment: Are the tests available and good? If so what kinds of tests are they?

Comment: @BillyChan There are some RSpec tests, but not enough.

Answer (score 3):

The answer here really depends how much autonomy you have and how much time you can devote to the refactor.  With a project of this size, almost certainly you can't just stop all work and devote 100% of your time towards the <del>cleanup</del> ROR 3 migration (*cough cough*, migration!).

If my assumption is correct, then my advice would be to tackle this in small chunks using the second method (e.g. update existing code).  In addition to what you've outlined, I would encourage a few other things:

- Write tests before you refactor a piece of code.  This will help you be confident that you're not introducing problems (emphasis on the *help*... some breakage is of course possible).
- Where possible, consider breaking modules into separate, independent gems.  This will help you to track external dependencies and figure out where all 45 of those external gems are getting used.  It will also help limit the scope of your tests.

Frankly the second method is much safer for your job as a developer, since it allows you to improve the codebase while simultaneously responding to other business needs.  If a portion of the refactor is going too slowly, you can also just stop and pick up elsewhere, since the rest of the codebase is still intact.

Comment: Completely agree - as much as we love to start from scratch as developers it often takes a lot longer than we expect, and sometimes the version in development never makes it out the door. Also +1 for writing tests before refactoring.

Comment: I understand your point of view, but the project modules and the project basis have big design errors. Some parts must be completely rewrited, and I think 'old tests' will not work at all.

Comment: I didn't say it was going to be easy.  :)  The big thing about this approach is that it lets you tackle things in small chunks and not lose several months of work rewriting the app.  Re: tests - you're certainly not obligated to use the old tests, especially if they're bad or broken.  Just recognize that the tests are there to help you be confident that you did the refactoring correctly, or at least, in a way such that you can update other dependent code in a predictable manner.  E.g. if you change an API, your tests will be your first new API consumer and the rest of the codebase follows.

Comment: @JonathanCairns - yup, I too have seen more than 1 from-scratch-rewrite fail to live up to the promises of cleaner/faster/smaller code.  It can cost a person his/her job!

Answer (score 2):

Refactoring is a lot of work, and will take a long time and a lot of thought.

In comparison with a totally new project, the problem is that you have to maintain a working project, and probably will have to support some bug fixes and feature requests as you go.

on the other hand you have a much better understanding of the problem you are solving, and you can use the existing software as your defacto "functional spec"

1. identify the Interfaces between your "modules", by listing each inter-dependency.
2. Clean up these "interfaces" if necessary
3. Formalize interfaces by Writing unit tests to test the input and output of each module
4. create totally new modules as drop in replacements.  architect from scratch, and do your ruby upgrade here.  Make sure your new modules pass the same tests as your old modules.
5. If necessary (as an interim solution) wrap various incompatible sections to get them working together.  this may be slow, but it's a stopgap.

good luck.

Comment: I like your method of "Interfaces" then tests. I'm now convinced it's the first step if we don't start from scratch. Thanks.